# BrowseForFolder() window does not open at the foreground, hides (Perl Win32::GUI)

Tags: windows, perl, winapi

When calling Perl `Win32::GUI::BrowseForFolder()`, the desktop (naturally) has several earlier windows on it. It turns out that the `BrowseForFolder()` window hides behind those windows. This is sometimes confusing and annoying, because you may not realize the program is asking you for a folder name, and you may think there is a bug. (This is in difference from (for example)  `Win32::GUI::GetOpenFileName()` or `GetSaveFileName()`, which do pop up at the foreground!).

My question is: how to make `BrowseForFolder()` come to the foreground?

One possibility is to find its handle, and then raise it to the foreground.

Note that `-addexstyle => WS_EX_TOPMOST` doesn't have an effect (see below).

Here is a complete (compileable and running) code example. (5.014 is not essential)

```
use strict;

use warnings;
use 5.014;      
use Win32::GUI();
use Win32::GUI qw{ WS_EX_TOPMOST};
my ($InputDir, $TopDir, $InputFileName, $dw, $dh, $desktop, $Window);

$TopDir = 'D:\My documents';    # Change this to an existing direcotry of yours
$desktop = Win32::GUI::GetDesktopWindow();
$dw = Win32::GUI::Width($desktop);
$dh = Win32::GUI::Height($desktop);
$Window = Win32::GUI::Window->new( -name => 'main', -text => 'Main window',
    -pos => [20/100*$dw, 20/100*$dh], -size => [50/100*$dw, 60/100*$dh],
    -onTerminate => \&TerminateWindow,
    -addexstyle => WS_EX_TOPMOST,   -dialogui => 1, -tabstop => 1, -cancel => 1, );
$Window -> AddButton ( -name => 'ButtonCommit', -pos => [10,10], 
    -size =>[16/100*$dw,3.5/100*$dh], -text => 'Commit changes', -onClick => \&Commit);
sub Commit {
$InputDir = Win32::GUI::BrowseForFolder( -root => $TopDir, -includefiles => 1,
                -title => 'Select directory for parameter file', 
                -text =>'Selext directory for parameter file',
                -size => [50/100*$dw, 50/100*$dh], -addexstyle => WS_EX_TOPMOST,);
$InputFileName = Win32::GUI::GetOpenFileName( -title  => 'Select the input file',
    -directory => $InputDir, -file   => "\0" . " " x 256,
    -filter => ["Text files (*.txt)" => "*.txt", "All files", "*.*", ],
    -text => 'text Select input file');
} # end sub Commit
$Window ->Show();
Win32::GUI::Dialog();
sub TerminateWindow {
return -1;
}
```

Click the "Commit changes" button, then minimize the main window, and only then you see the "hiding" `BrowseForFolder()` window.

Note that the `BrowseForFolder()` window hides behind other windows, and you need to minimize other windows to get to it. All other Perl `Win32::GUI` windows do open up at the foreground.

Furthermore, note that `-addexstyle => WS_EX_TOPMOST` doesn't have an effect, while it usually does in Perl `Win32::GUI` windows.

Note: change the `D:\My documents` to an existing directory.

Related question: How does one find the desktop windows handles? If we could find `BrowseForFolder()`'s handle, we could raise it to the foreground.

(Note: similar question cross-posted at PerlMonks: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=994815)

Answer (score 3):

If you remove

```
-addexstyle  => WS_EX_TOPMOST,
```

from main window (and also from the Browser), it jumps to foreground. The flag is used for windows that should be on top no matter what - typically some widgets.